# LINQ Group by and fetching date by descending order in select list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to figure out why does my LINQ isn't working as I want it:

```
Products.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID).Select(x => new ResultItem()
{
    ID = x.Key,
    SaleNumber = x.Sum(y => y.QuantityPurchased),
    SaleEarning = x.Sum(y => y.QuantityPurchased * y.SalePrice),
    Title = x.Select(y => y.Title).FirstOrDefault(),
    CurrentPrice = x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TransactionDate)
        .Select(y => y.SalePrice).FirstOrDefault(),
    SalePrice = x.Select(y => y.SalePrice).FirstOrDefault()
}).ToList();
```

As you can see I have a list of products where I group them by ItemID and then I'm trying to set for each item their price according to the latest date that they were sold.

This currently gives me completely wrong results for `CurrentPrice` column in select list... What am I doing wrong here?

P.S. This is the problematic part:

```
CurrentPrice = x.OrderBy(y => y.TransactionDate).Select(y => y.SalePrice).FirstOrDefault()
```

Any ideas guys?

P.S2:

Btw. guys the dates that I get in return are like this: `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` ... In DB the dates are all set correct and in C# they are datetime type...

And when I do something like this:

```
productTransactions.Where(x => x.ItemID == "//some id")
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.TransactionDate).ToList();
```

I get the correct results. The dates get ordered exactly like I want them , but in this group by they are completely messed up..

Comment: P.S. Guys I need to have dates ordered from newest to oldest and then select the newest sale price..

Comment: @GrantWinney yes I've tried that but it still doesn't works...

Comment: Change 'OrderBy' method with 'OrderByDescending'

Comment: @RezaArabQaeni Tried... Doesn't works still

Comment: It's very weird guy,s I have no idea what am I doing wrong here??

Comment: Have you tried looking at the generated SQL?

Comment: @DaniDev I haven't yet, I figured I'd trust LINQ enough to perform it like this ... Btw. the dates that I get in return are like this: {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM} ... In DB the dates are all set correct and in C# they are datetime type...

Comment: Profile SQL query generated and verify that on your data as your expecting.

Comment: @DaniDev Yeah but the dates shouldn't be 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM :D ... They are set in 2017 this year in db... Not sure what is linq doing with the statement, but I probably wrote the LINQ wrong ... ?

Comment: Is there any other way to write this LINQ?

Comment: your nested select statements are losing context ?
just a hunch: try this:   CurrentPrice = x.OrderByDescending(x => x.TransactionDate).Select(y=>y.SalePrice).FirstOrDefault(),

Comment: @DaniDev Tried, still doesn't works... :/

Comment: Maybe there is something messed up with entity mapping. Try to remove and add the specific entity from model

Comment: Can you show a small sample of the data from the database (and indicate what you expect the value for `CurrentPrice` to be and what you actually get

Comment: Also, you have said _I'm trying to set for each item their price according to the latest date that they were sold_ but your code is not doing that.

Comment: Show us the code for the `Product` class.

Comment: @StephenMuecke how can i modify my Linq so it does that? =)

Comment: Not sure without seeing a sample of the data and what you expect the result to be. And I'm a bit confused between `CurrentPrice` (which returns the price of the most item in the group) and `SalePrice` (which returns the price of the first item in the group - although since the items are not ordered it may give unexpected results)